# Regra de Select - Qual melhor forma?

Tags: sql, sqldeveloper

Bom dia!

O esquema seria o seguinte: tenho uma tabela 'a' com duas colunas, código_ben¹ e o cod_cons²

¹ Seria código do cliente;
² Seria o código da consulta.

Eu queria fazer um select mas não sei como realizar, selecionar os clientes que realizam o código de uma consulta (por exemplo cod 01) porém não chamar os códigos dos clientes se eles realizaram outros códigos (cod 02, 03, 04 e 05)

Creio se eu colocar o mesmo campo com COD_CONS = '01' e outro com AND COD_CONS NOT IN (02, 03, 04 e 05) causará ambiguidade ou não fará lógica. Tentei fazer com um JOIN na mesma tabela, mas, ocasionou alguma inconsistência (creio ter escrito algo errado)

Seria +/- assim:

SELECT * FROM table_a
WHERE cod_cons = '01'
AND cod_cons NOT IN ('02', '03', '04', '05')

ou mesmo faria um Join na mesma tabela:

SELECT * FROM table_a y
JOIN (SELECT cod_cons from table_a x WHERE x.cod_cons NOT IN ('02', '03', '04', '05')) x ON x.cod_cons = y.cod_cons
WHERE y.cod_cons = '01'

Comment: O `not in` me parece totalmente aceitável. Se não for assim, teria de fazer uma subquery e usar um `not exists`, o que "conceitualmente" significa a mesma coisa, só que mais complexo e **provavelmente** menos performático. Agora isso me parece que não retornar os dados certos, pq se o "01" ta numa linha e o "02" em outra, vai retornar a linha do "01", talvez a subquery seja a única solução que resolva isso, serial semelhante ao `join`, mas usar um `not exists`, isso deve resolver

Comment: O meu objetivo seria trazer todos os clientes que realizaram consul 01 somente se eles não realizaram as consultas listadas acima (02, 03, 04, 05) pois preciso filtrar com base de datas, por exemplo em 2020 ele pode ter realizado consul 01, logo em 2021 também esse consul 01 MAS realizou a listagem acima, logo, ele não deve vir na consulta do sql

Comment: qual é o database? oracle?

Comment: Sim, SQL ORACLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como eu comentei, pode resolver isso fazendo uma *subquery* que verique se **o mesmo** cliente que tem uma consulta "01" não tem as outras ("02", etc).

Pode resolver isso assim:

```
select a.*
  from table_a a
 where cod_cons='01'
   and not exists (select b.cod_ben
                     from table_a b
                    where a.cod_ben = b.cod_ben
                      and b.cod_cons in ('02','03','04','05')
                  );
```

Notas:

- O primeiro `select` é o que já tinhas feito, sem novidades
- O segundo tem o filtro (`WHERE` dos `cod_cons`) que não deseja, e garante que olha **para o mesmo registro de cliente** por causa do `where a.cod_ben = b.cod_ben`, ou seja, um *subselect* na mesma tabela, mas comparando com o registro de cliente do select principal.

Pode ver aqui funcionando (escrevi a query como `mysql` mas como o código está em `sql ansi` vai funcionar com `oracle`: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/87UirYH4gSk1czNVhiGQN1/0)

No que no exemplo, apenas os registros com id 1 e 7 tem somente `cod_cons = '01'`

Comment: Rapaz, obrigado, de coração ! TU é mestre mesmo, quando crescer quero ser igual você, deu certo aqui, peguei um código de cliente e validei.

Comment: que bom, não esqueça de aceitar a resposta, e é só prática mesmo, logo você vai estar respondendo as dúvidas tbm :)

Comment: parece que alguém não gostou da resposta, podia ao menos deixar um comentário dizendo o que tem de ruim o que pq não é útil para a comunidade